# F# Winforms Charts and Databinding: "Make chart based on tupled list"

Tags: winforms, charts, f#

I have a very long list of 73800 elements to be exact. I then use:

```
[the very long list]|> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList
```

to make a tupled list that looks like this:

```
[(4,32),(5,322)...]
```

My question is can i pass that tupled list to my Databind series ?

```
let series = new Series(ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column)
chart.Series.Add(series)
series.Points.DataBindXY([the very long list]|> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.toList)
```

The above code ofcourse doesn't work but i was wodnering if there is another Point.Databind property i can use that will accept that tupled list and set the x y values based on the two values in the tuples?

Or perhaps there is an option to to just pass the `[very long list]` to the series and then it will count the occurences on its own and make the `y` values based on number of occurences in the list?

Thanks

Comment: In other words it is a histogram i want to make based on a very long list.

Comment: I think `DataBind(tuples, "Item1", "Item2", null)` ought to do the trick.

Comment: I get the exception that Y values cannot be data bound to a string object.

Comment: This works for me: `series.Points.DataBind(["x",1;"y",2;"z",3], "Item1", "Item2", null)`

Comment: Yeah that seemed to work. I was using DataBindXY not just DataBind

Comment: you can make answer and ofcourse i will give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using DataVisualization I doubt you will find APIs taking tuples, as it's not C# idiomatic.

I recommend using F# Charting where there are apis supporting F# tuples, here is an example: https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/BarAndColumnCharts.html

Comment: it is not the first time you mention this Stuart and it is not because I am ignorant that i deny to use this F# charting but I doubt my teacher will accept I start using a 3rd party library.

Comment: Ah, I understand the context now. How about writing you own helper function?

Comment: I have tried but i end with a crazy running time which i know my teacher will also not accept. But i guess i have to rethink my approach. Just hoped there were a miracle hiding in the DataVisualization library.

Comment: Yeah, no miracles in afraid. If you share your code I might be able to help with performance

Comment: Atm i will say yes to all the help i can get. Here is a snippet with all my code. http://www.fssnip.net/7RN

Comment: I fixed something now to my satisfaction. Ofcourse still open to sugestions